# Python: Is there an easier way to remove and replace an item in a list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, replace

I was wondering if there was a more concise way of reassigning a random item from a list: setting the original item to a variable first, then replacing that item in the list with another pre-set variable.

listofwords is a list with 9 items in it.

```
random_val = random.randint(0,8)

removed_word = listofwords[randomval]
listofwords[randomval] = substitute_word
```

Comment: Note that you are not actually removing the list item.

Comment: Pedantic, but you are reassigning vs removing. If you want to remove and reinsert (which is slow btw) you would use `.pop(randomval)` then `.insert(randomval, substitute_word)`  But please don't do that. Just change what you call what you are doing. ;-)

Comment: Thanks dawg - edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can one-line the swap using `tuple` packing/unpacking, but that's about it; doesn't really improve the code much:

```
listofwords[randomval], removed_word = substitute_word, listofwords[randomval]
```

Comment: Note: The ordering I chose minimizes the time between reading `listofwords[randomval]` and writing back to it; Python's spec guarantees `listofwords[randomval]` is read last and written first using this ordering. It's a meaningless difference though; it narrows the race condition in the threaded case, but does not eliminate it (two threads doing a swap could get the same initial value instead of one thread getting the substituted value set by the other), so the difference based on ordering is pretty meaningless, I just like minimizing the time spent in an "unstable state" out of habit.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing that you could do to shorten your code would be to combine the last two assignments on a single line.

```
removed_word, listofwords[randomval] = listofwords[randomval], substitute_word
```

But this doesnt really make the code any more concise. If you have to do this a lot, you could turn this procedure into a function. But, there is no built-in method to do this, so your way seems good.

Answer (score 0):

To assign a variable to a list item, the shortest way is:

```
OldValue = ListOfWords[index]
```

And the shortest way to change an item in a list is:

```
ListOfWords[index] = NewValue
```

So no, there is no shorter way.

---

However, there is an easy way to swap variables.

```
ListOfWords = ["Hello", "Moon"]
Value = "World"
```

If you create Value with the value you want to change in, then use this:

```
ListOfWords[1], Value = Value, ListOfWords[1]
```

This would change `Value` to `ListOfWords[1]` and `ListOfWords[1]` to `Value`. In a shell:

```
>>> ListOfWords[1], Value = Value, ListOfWords[1]
>>> Value = "World"
>>> ListOfWords
['Hello', 'World']
>>> Value
'Moon'
```

---

As the other answers suggest, you can use the variable swap to substitute it in with `ListOfWords[1], OldValue = NewValue, ListOfWords[1]`